# how to get CDB info from a query on PDB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently running a SQL (below) on a PDB database to get certain info.
Is it possible to get the CDB info also using any of the columns below like the PDB_NAME or PDB_DBID, by using a join with some other view.

`select min(b.name) as PDB_NAME,min(b.dbid) as PDB_DBID,min(a.event_timestamp) as TIMESTAMP from audsys.aud$unified a,V$PDBS b where a.dbid=b.dbid`

I tried to check for any other views like cdb_pdbs ,but it didnt have what i needed

Comment: what do you mean by 'cdb info'?

Comment: CDB info like the CDB name

Comment: You can get such info from v$database.

Comment: oh yes indeed..it never occured to me that we can query v$database on a PDB as well.Thanks @gsalem